# Use HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped for All Instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, structuremap, idisposable

I use **structure map 4.5.1** in my ASP.NET MVC 5.x Web Application and I do Scan **Interface** implementations and add `HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()` for all of them with following codes:

```
 public static class SmObjectFactory
 {
    private static readonly Lazy<StructureMap.Container> _containerBuilder =
        new Lazy<StructureMap.Container>(DefaultContainer, LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);

    public static IContainer Container => _containerBuilder.Value;

    private static StructureMap.Container DefaultContainer()
    {
        return new StructureMap.Container(config =>
        {

            config.Scan(scanner =>
            {
                scanner.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(IPostService));
                scanner.WithDefaultConventions();
                scanner.SingleImplementationsOfInterface()
                       .OnAddedPluginTypes(expression =>  
                        expression.HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped());
            });
        });
    }
 }
```

1. When i use this code, `HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()` it do added for All Interfacs that inherent `IDisposable` Interface ? if answer is no how can I do this ?
2. When i Sholud not  use `HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped` is just a `life-time` specifier. so when you specify it, it will be used for all of the requested and configured instances and here it's not important that it's `IDisposable` or not. It's not about disposing anything, it's a life-time specifier.
- If you need new instances per each request from the IoC container, don't use it.

Comment: Great Answer Thanks @VahidN